# Discord.js, msg.content.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a discord bot using discord.js. I'm trying to make an if statement:

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    require('dotenv').config();
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    
    const config = require("./config.json");
    
    client.on('message', (msg) => {
        if (msg.content.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(`${config.prefix}${config.customcommand}`)) {
            msg.channel.send("It's working");
        }
    }

client.login(config.token)
```

Config.json:

```
    {
          "token": "xxx",
          "prefix": "C!",
          "customcommand": "Ship"
    }
```

Now I'm aware that .toLowerCase() only works with strings, that's why I used toString() but it doesn't work. Nothing is happening when I type the command (C!Ship)

Comment: How could a lowercase string start with "C!Ship" do you think?

Answer (score 1):

As [Robin Zigmond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8475054/robin-zigmond) said, you made the message content all lowercaps, so there's no scenario where it can start with "C!..." Hence, your if statement never runs.


You may have meant

```
{
  "token": "xxx",
  "prefix": "c!",
  "customcommand": "ship"
}
```

or this. According to [discordjs docs](https://discordjs-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_message.html#content), `msg.content` is already a string so `toString()` is not needed. Also, you may have missed a `);` when you copied and pasted on Stack Overflow.

```
client.on('message', (msg) => {
  if (msg.content.startsWith(`${config.prefix}${config.customcommand}`)) {
    msg.channel.send("It's working");
  }
});
```